# Delete Data on Mednafen

Tags: installation, package-management, uninstall, configuration

could you tell me to delete data on Mednafen? Uninstalling just only leave the data. not to delete the data, just delete installation.
I have a harmful command configuration. that's make me stuck! and can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Myself: use Synaptic packet manager, and then search for the package you want to Uninstall + config. see the green square dot over there? click that and select "mark to remove and data", that X with the Red Square Dot behind it. and yes!, You have reset the data and Install it back. :). if this doesn't work , please drop a comment before downvoting.

Comment: Remember that you can also use `sudo apt-get purge packagename`.